# Is there a word for the desire or emotion of wanting to prove someone wrong?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the motivation to do something only because of the desire to prove someone wrong? When someone is using reverse psychology like:

> You won't do this chore, you'll probably just mess it up anyway.

Are they preying on a particular characteristic? If successful, is the manipulated person acting with a particular emotion?

Comment: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/duty_calls.png

Comment: @oosterwal xkcd rules. xD

Answer (score 3):

For my two-penneth, I'd say that the person is acting out of "sheer bloody-mindedness". Meaning, "I will do this just because people say I can't (whether or not I think it's still a desirable thing to do)".

Don't know if this is only British English.

Edit: Seems to be only BE in this context according to MW.

Comment: The Americans have *ornery*, but I think that doesn't necessarily imply *deliberately* thwarting or proving someone else wrong (it might just be a side-effect of being set in one's ways, for example). Doing something out of *sheer bloody-mindedness" invariably means you're doing it to defy/discommode someone else, rather than simply because you wanted to anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The person who has been motivated by reverse psychology may be doing what they've been motivated to do out of **spite**.

Answer (score 1):

The desire or emotion of wanting to prove someone wrong? Here are some examples of words that express that sentiment, used in a phrase or sentence:

- Acting **contrary**
- Motivated to find fault as an expression of **schadenfreude**
- Behaving in a **truculent** manner
- Being **ornery**, **contentious** or **gratuitously fussy**.

Or either of the two answers provided already, both of which are quite  adequate.

Answer (score 0):

*Faultfinding* works here.  Same with peevish, but peevish isn't as precise.

EDIT: Oh! Sorry.

Well, to this, I'd use the phrase "chip on your shoulder" , or something with "underdog". Someone can be on a "crusade" or "on a mission"

But this perhaps delves into psychology.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question was interpreted in reverse. It seems to be asking for the characteristic of *a person who can be easily manipulated* by the use of reverse psychology, not the one doing the manipulating.

**Manipulable** describes such a person, as do the words **tractable**, **malleable**, and **pliable**.

You could also call such a person **easily swayed** or **easily influenced**.

Comment: Actually, now I'm stuck - the title asks one question ("Is there a word for the desire or emotion of wanting to prove someone wrong?") and the body asks another ("Are they preying on a particular characteristic?").